# Avoiding the obscuring of the y-axis by shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

On the Cartesian plane, a line and the standard parabola are plotted. A triangle having vertices at the intersection of the line and parabola and at a point on the parabola below the line is shaded. The shading slightly obscures the $y$-axis. How can I avoid this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}{4.5in}
\vskip0pt
\noindent \raggedright{\textbf{5.) }$y = mx + b$ is an equation for line $\ell$. If $b > 0$, the line and standard \\
parabola intersect at distinct points \textit{A} and \textit{B}. Among all triangles \\
with vertices at \textit{A} and \textit{B} and with a vertex on the parabola below \\
$\ell$, one encloses the biggest area. Compute the coordinates of the \\
vertex below $\ell$ of such a triangle.}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0cm}
%
\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]
\begin{axis}[width=2in, height=2in, axis equal image, unit vector ratio=2 1, axis on top, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4, domain=-4:4,
    ymin=-2,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-2:9,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x},ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=7.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=7.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

%A line and the standard parabola are plotted. A triangle with vertices at the intersection
%of the line and parabola and at a point on the parabola below the line is drawn.
\addplot[samples=501, domain=-3:3] {x^2};
\addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, domain=-4:4] {(-2/3)*x + 4};

%A and B are the intersections of the line and parabola.
%x-intercept of the tangent line.
\coordinate (A) at ({-(1+sqrt(37))/3},{(38+2*sqrt(37))/9});
\coordinate (B) at ({-(1-sqrt(37))/3},{(38-2*sqrt(37))/9});
\coordinate (C) at (-1,1);

\coordinate (P) at (2.875,8.265625);
\coordinate (Q) at (1.4375,0);

\coordinate (S) at (-4,20/3);
\coordinate (T) at (0,4);

\end{axis}


\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=orange, opacity=0.5] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;


\node[anchor=center, font=\scriptsize] at ($(S)!-0.15cm!(T)$){$\ell$};

%A "pin" is drawn to A.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (P) -- ($(P)!0.75cm!90:(Q)$) node[anchor=west, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=0]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$y=x^{2}$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `axis on top`? To make this work, you need to move the fills inside the `axis` environment.

Comment: @marmot  Yep. I appreciate the help. Peter Grill suggested `axis on top=true`. What is the difference between `axis on top` and `axis on top=true`?

Comment: `axis on top=true` takes longer to be typed. ;-)

Comment: @marmot: I think the reason I got used to using the verbose mode `axis on top=true` is that I have many styles and if I use one of these styles, but desire to override one particular setting, it is obvious what to do when you see `axis on top=true` in the style definition. If the styles simply said `axis on top`, I would have to look up how to disable it. Is it `axis on top=false` or is there another `axis on bottom` that I need to use to override this?

Comment: @PeterGrill AFAIK `axis on top` installs a set of "standard" layers along with a specific ordering. (Side remark: for polar axes it is more tricky, I think.) One way to "undo" it is to say `set layers=standard`, I think. I never tried `axis on top=false`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Here is ssome somewhat more precise information: if you look at `pgfplots.code.tex`, you'll find `/pgfplots/layers/axis on top/.define layer set={axis background,pre main,main,axis grid,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,axis descriptions,axis foreground}{
                /pgfplots/layers/standard
        },`. That is, `axis on top=false` and  `set layers=standard,` seem to be equivalent. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option for that: `axis on top=true` which yields:

[image]

### Note:

- Any fill/drawing should be done *within* the `axis` environment.  The reason for this is that `axis on top=true` defers the drawing of the axis until `\end{axis}` is encountered. If any fill/drawing is done )*after* it will obscure the axis.

  In the MWE below, I moved the code for the triangle to be *before* `\end{axis}`.
- I commented out the text portion of the code as it was not relevant to the problem. Also, do note the trailing `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}
%
%\noindent \begin{minipage}{4.5in}
%\vskip0pt
%\noindent \raggedright{\textbf{5.) }$y = mx + b$ is an equation for line $\ell$. If $b > 0$, the line and standard \\
%parabola intersect at distinct points \textit{A} and \textit{B}. Among all triangles \\
%with vertices at \textit{A} and \textit{B} and with a vertex on the parabola below \\
%$\ell$, one encloses the biggest area. Compute the coordinates of the \\
%vertex below $\ell$ of such a triangle.}
%\end{minipage}
%%
%\hspace{0cm}
%%
%\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]
%{
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]
\begin{axis}[width=2in, height=2in, axis equal image, unit vector ratio=2 1, axis on top, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4, domain=-4:4,
    ymin=-2,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-2:9,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x},ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=7.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=7.5pt, anchor=south west},
    axis on top=true,
]

%A line and the standard parabola are plotted. A triangle with vertices at the intersection
%of the line and parabola and at a point on the parabola below the line is drawn.
\addplot[samples=501, domain=-3:3] {x^2};
\addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, domain=-4:4] {(-2/3)*x + 4};

%A and B are the intersections of the line and parabola.
%x-intercept of the tangent line.
\coordinate (A) at ({-(1+sqrt(37))/3},{(38+2*sqrt(37))/9});
\coordinate (B) at ({-(1-sqrt(37))/3},{(38-2*sqrt(37))/9});
\coordinate (C) at (-1,1);

\coordinate (P) at (2.875,8.265625);
\coordinate (Q) at (1.4375,0);

\coordinate (S) at (-4,20/3);
\coordinate (T) at (0,4);

\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

\end{axis}




\node[anchor=center, font=\scriptsize] at ($(S)!-0.15cm!(T)$){$\ell$};

%A "pin" is drawn to A.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (P) -- ($(P)!0.75cm!90:(Q)$) node[anchor=west, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=0]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$y=x^{2}$}};

\end{tikzpicture}% <-- Note: This % here prevents spurious spaces.
%}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot: Thanks. Was just in the process of fixing that. Also, for the record, I prefer things that take longer to type!! :-)

Comment: Well, obviously you are not born with claws. ;-)

Comment: I would like dots indicating the vertices to obscure the region bound by the triangle - or to be on top. Do I simply put the commands for them after the command for coloring the region bound by the triangle?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire: Not sure I fully understand what you are asking, but yes, add any other drawing _before_ `end{axis}`. The `axis on top` ensures that the _axis_ is drawn at  `end{axis}` so will be on top of any drawing you do.

Comment: Why do you say that the command `\draw[fill=orange] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;` should be issued within the `axis` environment?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire: I expanded the _Notes_ section to try to explain this. Let me know if there is still some confusion.